# add greenscript dependency on heroku

Tags: heroku, playframework, greenscript

Tried to add greenscript, with dependencies.yml

```
require:
- play 1.2.4
- play -> greenscript 1.2.7
```

running fine locally, but a push at heroku shows:

```
-----> Heroku receiving push
-----> Play! app detected
-----> Installing ivysettings.xml..... done
-----> Building Play! application...
       ~        _            _
       ~  _ __ | | __ _ _  _| |
       ~ | '_ \| |/ _' | || |_|
       ~ |  __/|_|\____|\__ (_)
       ~ |_|            |__/
       ~
       ~ play! 1.2.4, http://www.playframework.org
       ~
       ~ Oops,
       ~ Module not found: /tmp/build_p13kgit0jeq0/.play/modules/greenscript-1.2.7
       ~
       Building Play! application at directory ./
       Resolving dependencies: .play/play dependencies ./ --forProd --forceCopy --silent -Duser.home=/tmp/build_p13kgit0jeq0 2
&1
       ~ Oops,
       ~ Module not found: /tmp/build_p13kgit0jeq0/.play/modules/greenscript-1.2.7
       ~
 !     Failed to build Play! application
 !     Cleared Play! framework from cache
 !     Heroku push rejected, failed to compile Play! app
```

Is that the correct way to declare dependencies for play app in heroku?

Comment: Just tried this with an app I created from scratch and it worked fine.  Can you try the push again?  Maybe there was a transient network error downloading the module.

Comment: Experienced these: (1) remove greenscript from yml, push. (2) app can start, console said lib/ and module/ not sync. (3) I run 'heroku run play dependencies --sync', said module removed. (4) add back greenscript to yml, push, dependency resolved app can start! (5) modify some other file and push again, it said 'Oops, Module not found' again...

Comment: I've posted a [simple test app on GitHub](https://github.com/jamesward/helloplaygreenscript) that works for me.  Can you see what the differences are?  Maybe you committed your `modules` or `lib` directory to git?

Comment: I think I know the problem. I have specified in appication.conf with entry like 'module.greenscript=${play.path}/modules/greenscript-1.2.7' where heroku cannot resolve the ${play.path} variable.

Comment: Ah.  I think that is the old way of doing modules.  You shouldn't need to have that line anymore.

Answer (score 2):

It is found that the following application.conf cause the problem

```
module.greenscript=${play.path}/modules/greenscript-1.2.7
```

And there is no need to define module in this old way. Remove the line and deployment is fine now. Thx James.